# OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-05-22 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

this line of code is giving out of bounds error

```
    dim_data["mmm yy"] = pd.to_datetime(dim_data["mmm yy"])
```

dim_data["mmm yy"] is pandas.core.series.Series

```
    dim_data["mmm yy"]
    0     May 22
    1     May 22
    2     May 22
    3     May 22
    4     May 22
           ...  
    87    Jul 22
    88    Jul 22
    89    Jul 22
    90    Jul 22
    91    Jul 22
    Name: mmm yy, Length: 92, dtype: object
```

I want to convert the data of  dim_data["mmm yy"] from series to MMM YY datetime .

I'm not able to fix this error ,any help would be appreciated .

Comment: `dim_data["mmm yy"] = pd.to_datetime(dim_data["mmm yy"], format='%b %d')`